# Teamcity VCS (Git ssh) List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, teamcity

Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCq7W.png)

**Error message:**

> List remote refs failed:
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem:
>   ssh://git@git.assembla.com:22: Passphrase for
>   /Users/teamcity/.ssh/id_rsa

I tried the following things:

1. make new id_rsa.pub at build server PC
2. upload to my assembla account ssh setting and test git clone. (success)
3. build server id_rsa.pub copy to build agent PC (Windows10) - 
   path - C:/cygwin/home/"userName"/.ssh and C:/Users/"userName"/.ssh

   test git clone. (success)
4. retry Test Connection and show fail message

plz help me..

### teamcity-vcs.log at build server PC

jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://git@git.assembla.com:22: Passphrase for /Users/teamcity/.ssh/id_rsa
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.OperationContext.wrapException(OperationContext.java:164)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:357)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getCurrentState(GitVcsSupport.java:139)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.TestConnectionCommand.checkFetchConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:95)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.TestConnectionCommand.testConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:68)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.testConnection(GitVcsSupport.java:265)
    at jetbrains.vcs.api.services.impl.TestConnectionServiceProvider$1.testConnection(TestConnectionServiceProvider.java:1)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.TestConnectionCommand.runTestConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:37)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.TestConnectionCommand.doTestConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:27)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.EditVcsRootsController.doPost(EditVcsRootsController.java:263)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController$1.handleRequest(BaseFormXmlController.java:53)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.AjaxRequestProcessor.processRequest(AjaxRequestProcessor.java:45)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController.doHandle(BaseFormXmlController.java:51)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseController.handleRequestInternal(BaseController.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.TeamCityDispatcherServlet.service(TeamCityDispatcherServlet.java:3)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.doFilter(DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.java:11)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.doFilter(DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.java:5)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.diagnostic.web.DiagnosticFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticFilter.java:12)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.ResponseFragmentFilter.doFilter(ResponseFragmentFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://git@git.assembla.com:22: Passphrase for /Users/teamcity/.ssh/id_rsa
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.AuthSettings$1.get(AuthSettings.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProviderUserInfo.promptPassphrase(CredentialsProviderUserInfo.java:98)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:119)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:374)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:352)

Comment: Are there any related messages in `teamcity-vcs.log` (you might need to switch logging preset to `debug-vcs`)?

Comment: @cyberskunk log added !! plz help me T.T

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity does not support `Default Private key` with non-empty passphrase. So you should use private key with empty passphrase, or you might use `Uploaded Key` option as an alternative, see [SSH Keys Management](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/SSH+Keys+Management) for details.

Comment: Having an empty passphrase fixed this for me.